# setup uriworkermap.properties to run one tomcat site on tomcat root (without any contexts) with IIS using jk connector

Tags: iis, tomcat

I have one jsp site under webapps/ROOT of tomcat (accessible by doing http://localhost:8080)and want all requests from IIS to go to tomcat's root site (without having to give contexts in uriworkermap.properties) using jk connector. How should I define the uriworkermap.properties file in this case?

(My IIS Tomcat implementation is working fine using contexts.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out with testing. In uriworkermap.properties, put:

```
/*|/*=bal_worker1
/*.jsp=bal_worker1
```

where bal_worker1 is name of the worker.